# html formatted text and canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I've got a bunch of content which is html formatted, a combination of h1, ul, and p. 
I'm incorporating this content into a page which now uses canvas to create a gantt chart.

Is there a way to include the html within the canvas?
As the content currently exists as a blob, the thought of extracting it and putting it into a different format is a bit daunting, and there is little consistency across the content, meaning not each entry has all the same tags and structure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the canvas element isn't great at drawing text. You should probably just float your html formatted text over the canvas chart.